# Viewing parse backend result in android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have been struggling with this issue for the past 3 days and could not figure it out. I am not so sure what am I missing and I was hoping for some clarification, please.

Basically, I am building this app where I finished how to send and receive texts, same goes for pictures and videos. However, I decided to include an option for the user to create a questionnaire and send it to the user's inbox. Everything has been a success so far except for the questionnaire part. I am using parse.com as backend. I was able to save the data in parse. So, the user is able to create the questionnaire but when the he/she finishes creating the questionnaire and click the button to view the list of recipients to send it to, the app crashes. I tried retrieving the data in recipients activity and switch intent in Vote activity but no success, it keeps on crashing. The problem occurs in Vote activity and recipients activity that I have posted the code for both below. I will be grateful for some directions or guidance please.

```
public class VoteActivity extends Activity {

    private Vote vote;
    private EditText mainText;
    private EditText mTextOne;
    private EditText mTextTwo;
    private EditText mTextThree;
    private String postmaintText;
    private String posttextOne;
    private String posttextTwo;
    private String posttextThree;
    private Button mButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vote);

        Intent intent = this.getIntent();

         mainText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.questionVote);
         mTextOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.choiceOne);
         mTextTwo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.choiceTwo);
         mTextThree = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.choiceThree);



         mButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.createQ);
         mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {

                 postmaintText = mainText.getText().toString();
                 posttextOne = mTextOne.getText().toString();
                 posttextTwo = mTextTwo.getText().toString();
                 posttextThree = mTextThree.getText().toString();


                 postmaintText.trim();
                 posttextOne.trim();
                 posttextTwo.trim();
                 posttextThree.trim();

                 if (postmaintText.isEmpty() || posttextOne.isEmpty() || posttextTwo.isEmpty()|| posttextThree.isEmpty())
                 {
                     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(VoteActivity.this);
                     builder.setMessage(R.string.voteMessage)
                             .setTitle(R.string.vote_error_title)
                             .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,null);
                     AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                     dialog.show();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     final ParseObject post = new ParseObject("Messages");
                     post.put("questionare", postmaintText);
                     post.put("optionOne", posttextOne);
                     post.put("optionTwo", posttextTwo);
                     post.put("optionThree", posttextThree);
                     post.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                         @Override
                         public void done(ParseException e) {

                         if (e==null) {
                         // questioner posted successfully
                             vote = new Vote (post.getObjectId(), postmaintText, posttextOne, posttextTwo,posttextThree);
                             Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             ***// below is the intent where the list of recipents will be displayed for the user, that is where the app crashes***
                             Intent intent = new Intent(VoteActivity.this, recipientsActivity.class);
                             startActivity(intent);

                         }
                         else {

                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                         }


                         }
                     });


                 }

             }
         });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_vote, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

***Below is the recipients activity***

```
public class recipientsActivity extends ListActivity {

    public static final String TAG = recipientsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    protected List<ParseUser> mFriends;
    protected ParseRelation<ParseUser> mFriendsRelation;
    protected ParseUser mCurrentUser;
    protected MenuItem mSendMenuItem;
    protected Uri mMediaUri;
    protected String mFileType;
    protected String mMyMessage;
    protected String mMainquestionare;
    protected String mOptionone;
    protected String mOptiontwo;
    protected String mOptionthree;
    private List<Vote> mVotes;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipients);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        mMediaUri = getIntent().getData();
        mFileType = getIntent().getExtras().getString(parseConstants.KEY_FILE_TYPE);
        //***************
        mMyMessage = getIntent().getExtras().getString("themessage");
        //***************
        mMainquestionare = getIntent().getExtras().getString("questionare");
        mOptionone = getIntent().getExtras().getString("optionOne");
        mOptiontwo = getIntent().getExtras().getString("optionTwo");
        mOptionthree = getIntent().getExtras().getString("optionThree");

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        mFriendsRelation = mCurrentUser.getRelation(parseConstants.KEY_FRIENDS_RELATION);

        setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = mFriendsRelation.getQuery();
        query.addAscendingOrder(parseConstants.KEY_USERNAME);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>()

        {
            // friends
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> friends, ParseException e) {
                setProgressBarIndeterminate(false);
                if (e == null) {
                    mFriends = friends;
                    String[] usernames = new String[mFriends.size()];
                    int i = 0;
                    for (ParseUser user : mFriends) {
                        usernames[i] = user.getUsername();
                        i++;
                    }
                    // check list
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                            (getListView().getContext(),
                                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,
                                    usernames);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(recipientsActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                            .setTitle(R.string.error_title)
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_recipients, menu);
        mSendMenuItem = menu.getItem(0);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_send:
                ParseObject message = createMessage();
                //send(message);
                if (message == null) {
                    // error
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.error_selecting_file)
                            .setTitle(R.string.error_selecting_file_title)
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                } else {
                    send(message);
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        // show the number of recipents that are checked
        if (l.getCheckedItemCount() > 0) {
            mSendMenuItem.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            mSendMenuItem.setVisible(false);
        }

    }

    protected ParseObject createMessage() {
        ParseObject message = new ParseObject(parseConstants.CLASS_MESSAGES);
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(parseConstants.CLASS_MESSAGES);
        query.whereEqualTo("senderName", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
        message.put(parseConstants.KEY_SENDER_ID, ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
        message.put(parseConstants.KEY_SENDER_NAME, ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
        message.put(parseConstants.KEY_RECIPIENT_IDS, getRecipientIds());
        message.put(parseConstants.KEY_FILE_TYPE, mFileType);


        //*************
        if (mFileType.equals(parseConstants.TYPE_TEXT)) {
            message.put("themessage", mMyMessage);
            message.put(parseConstants.KEY_FILE_TYPE, "message");
            return message;
        } else if (mFileType.equals(parseConstants.TYPE_QUESTIONARE)) {
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {

                        String myQuestonare = mMainquestionare.toString();
                        String myOptionOne = mOptionone.toString();
                        String myOptionTwo = mOptiontwo.toString();
                        String myOptionThree = mOptionthree.toString();
                        Log.d("Brand", "Retrieved " + myQuestonare + " question" + myOptionOne + myOptionTwo + myOptionThree);

                        //  mVotes.clear();
                        // for (ParseObject vote :parseObjects ) {
                        //Vote vote1 = new Vote (vote.getObjectId("questionare"));
                        //mVotes.add(vote1);


                    }
                    else

                    {
                        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error: " + e.getMessage());

                    }
                }

            });
        } else {
            //***************


            byte[] fileBytes = FileHelper.getByteArrayFromFile(this, mMediaUri);

            if (fileBytes == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                if (mFileType.equals(parseConstants.TYPE_IMAGE)) {
                    fileBytes = FileHelper.reduceImageForUpload(fileBytes);
                }
                String fileName = FileHelper.getFileName(this, mMediaUri, mFileType);
                ParseFile file = new ParseFile(fileName, fileBytes);
                message.put(parseConstants.KEY_FILE, file);
                return message;
            }
            //***********
        }
        //***********
return message;
    }


    protected ArrayList<String> getRecipientIds() {
        ArrayList<String> recipientIds = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < getListView().getCount(); i++) {
            if (getListView().isItemChecked(i)) {
                recipientIds.add(mFriends.get(i).getObjectId());
            }
        }
        return recipientIds;
    }


protected void createQ()
{

}
   protected void send (ParseObject message) {
            message.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // sucessful
                    Toast.makeText(recipientsActivity.this, R.string.success_message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(recipientsActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.error_sending_message)
                            .setTitle(R.string.error_selecting_file_title)
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    }
```

***messageAdapter***

```
public class messageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <ParseObject> {

protected Context mContext;
protected List<ParseObject> mMessages;

public messageAdapter(Context context, List<ParseObject> messages) {

    super(context, R.layout.message_item, messages);
    mContext = context;
    mMessages = messages;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.message_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.iconImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.messageIcon);
        holder.nameLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.senderLabel);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ParseObject message = mMessages.get(position);

    if (message.getString(parseConstants.KEY_FILE_TYPE).equals(parseConstants.TYPE_IMAGE)) {
        holder.iconImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_new_picture);
    }
     else if (message.getString(parseConstants.KEY_FILE_TYPE).equals(parseConstants.TYPE_VIDEO)){
        holder.iconImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_video);
    }else {
        holder.iconImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_edit);
    }

        holder.nameLabel.setText(message.getString(parseConstants.KEY_SENDER_NAME));
        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView iconImageView;
        TextView nameLabel;
    }
}
```

***inboxFragment***

```
public class InboxFragment extends ListFragment {


protected List<ParseObject> mMessages;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inbox, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
// we are going to query the new message class that we just created in parse
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(parseConstants.CLASS_MESSAGES);
    query.whereEqualTo(parseConstants.KEY_RECIPIENT_IDS, ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
    query.addDescendingOrder(parseConstants.KEY_CREATED_AT);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> messages, ParseException e) {
            getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminate(false);

            if(e == null) {
                //we found messages!
                mMessages = messages;
                String[] usernames = new String[mMessages.size()];
                int i = 0;
                for (ParseObject message : mMessages) {
                    usernames[i] = message.getString(parseConstants.KEY_SENDER_NAME);
                    i++;
                }
                // check list
               messageAdapter adapter = new messageAdapter(
                       getListView().getContext(),
                       mMessages);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    ParseObject message = mMessages.get(position);
    String messageType = message.getString(parseConstants.KEY_FILE_TYPE);
    String senderName = message.getString(parseConstants.KEY_SENDER_NAME);
    String displayMessage = message.getString(parseConstants.KEY_MESSAGE);
    String createdDate = message.getString(parseConstants.KEY_CREATED_AT);

    ParseFile file = message.getParseFile(parseConstants.KEY_FILE);
    if (messageType.equals(parseConstants.TYPE_IMAGE)) {
        //view the image
        Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(file.getUrl());
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ViewImageActivity.class);
        intent.setData(fileUri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else if (messageType.equals(parseConstants.TYPE_VIDEO)) {
        Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(file.getUrl());
        //view the video
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, fileUri);
        intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "video/*");
        startActivity(intent);

    }
       else if (messageType.equals(parseConstants.TYPE_QUESTIONARE)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        startActivity(intent);



    }else if (messageType.equals(parseConstants.TYPE_TEXT)){

        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),  displayMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Message from: " + senderName + ".");
        builder.setMessage(displayMessage);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }


    //delete the message
    List<String> ids = message.getList(parseConstants.KEY_RECIPIENT_IDS);

    if(ids.size() == 1) {
        //last recipient, delete the message
        message.deleteInBackground();

    }else {
        //remove recipients name
        ids.remove(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());

        ArrayList<String> idsToRemove = new ArrayList<String>();
        idsToRemove.add(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());

        message.removeAll(parseConstants.KEY_RECIPIENT_IDS, idsToRemove);
        message.saveInBackground();
    }
}
    }
```

***Log cat***

```
    09-28 17:26:44.645      593-593/com.abdul.uniapp D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
09-28 17:26:44.645      593-593/com.abdul.uniapp D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
09-28 17:26:44.645      593-593/com.abdul.uniapp D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
09-28 17:26:44.645      593-593/com.abdul.uniapp D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
09-28 17:26:53.595     593-2102/com.abdul.uniapp I/System.out﹕ ParseRequest.NETWORK_EXECUTOR-thread-5 calls detatch()
09-28 17:26:53.615      593-593/com.abdul.uniapp D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:90 height:90 bitmap id is 288
09-28 17:26:53.695      593-593/com.abdul.uniapp I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
09-28 17:26:53.705      593-593/com.abdul.uniapp D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:48 height:48 bitmap id is 289
09-28 17:26:53.715      593-593/com.abdul.uniapp E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
09-28 17:26:53.715      593-593/com.abdul.uniapp D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:72 height:72 bitmap id is 290
09-28 17:26:53.725      593-593/com.abdul.uniapp D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:144 height:144 bitmap id is 291
09-28 17:26:53.725      593-593/com.abdul.uniapp I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
09-28 17:26:53.735      593-593/com.abdul.uniapp D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
09-28 17:26:53.745      593-593/com.abdul.uniapp D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 8
09-28 17:26:53.745      593-593/com.abdul.uniapp D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
09-28 17:26:53.745      593-593/com.abdul.uniapp D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:72 height:72 bitmap id is 292
09-28 17:26:53.745      593-593/com.abdul.uniapp D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-28 17:26:53.745      593-593/com.abdul.uniapp W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417e0da0)
09-28 17:26:53.745      593-593/com.abdul.uniapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.abdul.uniapp, PID: 593
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abdul.uniapp/com.abdul.uniapp.recipientsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2453)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.abdul.uniapp.recipientsActivity.onCreate(recipientsActivity.java:58)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2453)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-28 17:26:55.505      593-593/com.abdul.uniapp I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 593 SIG: 9
09-28 17:26:55.625    2130-2130/com.abdul.uniapp I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
09-28 17:26:55.645    2130-2130/com.abdul.uniapp I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority , spota verifySig and checkHash pass. priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-G900T_4.4.2_0034
09-28 17:26:55.645    2130-2130/com.abdul.uniapp I/SELinux﹕ selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
09-28 17:26:55.645    2130-2130/com.abdul.uniapp E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> Normal User
09-28 17:26:55.645    2130-2130/com.abdul.uniapp E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> com.abdul.uniapp [ userId:0 | appId:10242 ]
```

Comment: I have added my log cat in the post
Thanks

Comment: Do you have Recipients activity declared in your `AndroidManifest.xml`? Can you include that as well?

Comment: I have added recipients in my manifest. It has been included in my original post 
Thanks

Comment: I still do not see a stacktrace. Did you post it?

Comment: I did added the stack trace, but it was taking off for some reason.  Let me try again

Comment: I just added the stack trace, check it out Emmanuel 

Thanks

Comment: Line 58 of `RecipientsActivity` is throwing a `NullPointerException`

Comment: Thanks, 
I know where the problem is at. You were right, it was at line 58. 
But how did you know that this line was causing the problem if I may ask? 

Thank you very much Emmanuel

Comment: I just looked at the stacktrace.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much Emmanuel.  Really grateful